# Terminal printing on file is being shrank with ellipses

Tags: command-line, bash, printing

I am running a command like this: `command > output.txt` but my `output.txt` is having `"...43 more items"` written on it because the command prints too many things, it is like:

```
{
this is a text
text again
[more text,
more text
...43 more items
],
text again
}
```

Any help on how to make `output.txt` save all the lines without shrinking it with the "...43 more items" is very appreciated!
Thank you :)

EDIT: My command is this one `force:mdapi:describemetadata` (source: [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm))

Comment: This fully depends on your "command".

Comment: oh, i cannot force it to print all the lines no matter what command? I've updated the question with the command anyway :)

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. The "command" gives some output and it is saved to file. You  can change the command to give some other output, or filter the results by some text processing apps, like grep, sed,awk, etc

Comment: Screencast is needed. Please record a GIF using byzanz-record and share it in the question.

Comment: Thank you Karel, it helps! I will try to check from there :)